# How to make screen go fullscreen android

Tags: android

i have used

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

added this to manifest.xml

```
 <activity
 android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication" />
```

and added

```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

to my theme still i get this result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmPFK.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

Theme:

```xml
    <style name="Theme.SpakChat.FullScreen" parent="Theme.SpakChat">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

Your activity xml **root** view:

```xml
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> <---- added
```

Your activity:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // added
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )

        setContentView(binding.root)
....
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use normally this function to make my activities fullscreen. You can add it in a Utils folder and use it in any activity you want.

```
 public static void setFullScreen(Activity activity){
        View decor_View = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();

        int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you need to use `AppCompat` Theme with extension `.Fullscreen`:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen" ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you want to apply this only to some Activities then do it inside `<activity` instead of `<application`.